# Display ads using shortcode in the middle of post exept certain categories Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an advertisement plugin which displays ads using shortcodes. I already have added ads on top and bottom of post, but also I need to add my ad shortcode into middle of post **exept certain categories** and make it show ads only in posts wich have not less than 1000 symbols lenght. For that purpose for now I have found following code which should be inserted in single.php and replace 
`<?php the_content();?>` line, but it does not exactly what I need:

```
<?php
$paragraphAfter= 3; //display after the 3 paragraph
$content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());
$content = explode("</p>", $content);
for ($i = 0; $i <count($content); $i++ ) {
if ($i == $paragraphAfter) { ?>
                      <div style="text-align: center"><?php echo do_shortcode("[my_shortcode]"); ?></div>
<?php }
echo $content[$i] . "</p>";
} ?>
```

It displays ads after 3-rd paragraph of all posts, I need to improove it to work only in certain categories and in posts wich have not less than 1000 symbols lengt. And, if it is possible, make it able to found the middle of post in more accurate way. And, please, provide a clear instruction what code and where should I replace, coding isnt my strong suit at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a robot and I'm not doing any kind of commercial, I had the same problem and I use a plugin called "Ad Inserter", it fixed my problems,

Here is the link on wordpress website:
https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/ad-inserter/